# Find strings with a particular pattern

Tags: r, string, parsing, dplyr

I have a large data set with sentences. Here is a sample.

```
sample0 = data.frame(contents = c("the result of this analysis is a ratio of 480:1. the compensation committee continuously reviews both the compensation of our ceo, our neos and our pay practices for all team members to ensure internal equity is appropriate. ",
                    "annual total compensation of our ceo was $15,682,219, the 2018 annual total compensation of our median compensated employee was $55,426, and the ratio of these amounts is 283 to 1. "))
```

From the sample, I want to extract a ratio. The first one has "480:1" and second one has "283 to 1".  If I want to extract "# to #" or "#:#" (number to number or number:number formats). How can I do it? Each cell may have multiple ratios.

---- edit 
Thanks to @camille, I have this

```
str_extract_all(sample0, regex("\\d+(\\:| to )\\d+",ignore_case = T)) %>% unlist()
```

However, for some elements in the vector, I have multiple matched cases. How can I get all the matched cases for each element? Is there a way using `dplyr` with `mutate` function?

Comment: Use regex with a pattern such as `\\d+(\\:| to )\\d+`

Comment: Thank you for comments. can you explain it in more detail?

Comment: There are other SO posts on extracting all matches of a regex pattern, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30182278/5325862). The pattern I suggested matches 1 or more digits, then either a colon or " to ", then 1 or more digits

Comment: For some, I have multiple matched cases. How can I have all the matched cases?

Comment: You're using `str_extract_all`, so you are getting all matched cases. Please post an example where you think you are missing some. (Perhaps the `unlist` is confusing you? If your input has length 2, `str_extract_all` will return a list of length `2`, with all matches for the first sentence in the first list element and all matches for the second sentence in the second list element. When you `unlist`, it puts all the matches in a vector, with no way to tell which match came from which sentence.)

Comment: You shouldn't need to wrap the pattern in anything, since `stringr` functions expect regex patterns. You're also calling this on a data frame, where you probably want to be calling it on just the vector of text, i.e. `sample0$contents`

Comment: Thank you, guys. If a number has decimal values like 480.03 : 1, how can I extract it?